# How do I work with Excel and QGIS so that Excel formulas are intact when data is edited in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, excel, spreadsheet

I work a lot with Excel spreadsheets that are linked across multiple tabs and files. In this case, I have a sheet with coordinates and a whole lot of other data fields which needs to be imported into QGIS. Because this raw data is pretty messy and has a bunch of fields that does not need to be imported into my map, I like to create a new sheet and do a index-match to get a clean dataset for mapping.

What I've realized is that after I use the Spreadsheet Layers plugin to import my point layer, I am unable to edit data in the layer without breaking the Excel formulas which keep my data connection to the original source data "live" (i.e. the moment I make an edit in the layer, my excel data becomes hard-coded).

How can I maintain the live connection while having the flexibility to manually edit data?